# How to handle Intent with Kotlin and Conductor

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-view, kotlin

I have three Views and One activity.
MainActivity - MainController - PushedController - NotificationOpenController.

The MainController contains a button, when pressed does some *black box* stuff and the device recieves a notification in the notification tray.

When the notification is clicked, I want the behavior to be as if

```
router.pushController(RouterTransaction.with(NotificationOpenController(bundle))
            .pushChangeHandler(VerticalChangeHandler())
            .popChangeHandler(VerticalChangeHandler()))
```

just happened.

**Any Kotlin related tips or revisions are appreciated as I'm doing this to learn the language**

I was unsure how to achieve this in a proper way through the Intents, perhaps a broadcast? but after some trial and error my code now looks like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    App.graph.inject(this)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_kotlin)
    Log.d(TAG,"${FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()}")


    router = Conductor.attachRouter(this, controller_container, savedInstanceState)

    val startingIntent : Intent? = intent
    if(startingIntent?.extras != null){
        transitionToNotificationOpenController(startingIntent?.extras)
    }
    else{
        if (!router.hasRootController()) {
            router.setRoot(RouterTransaction.with(MainController()));
        }
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (!router.handleBack()) {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

fun transitionToNotificationOpenController(bundl: Bundle?){ 
   router.pushController(RouterTransaction.with(NotificationOpenController(bundl))
            .pushChangeHandler(VerticalChangeHandler())
            .popChangeHandler(VerticalChangeHandler()))
}
```

The Notification Intent is built like this

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Text")
    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message",messageBody)
    val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
...
manager.notify(1,builder.build())
```

However, using this approach the animation gets all wrong, and the user can only see the "typical"   - popup view after loading some  or launching new activity-
since there is a Activity Resume when pressing the notification,  followed by Activity Pause -> Activity Resume after pressing the backbutton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieved desired result.

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        >
```

MainActivity:

```
override fun onResume(){
    super.onResume()
    val bundle : Bundle? = intent.extras
    if (bundle != null){
        transitionToNotificationOpenController(bundle)
    }
}

/**
 * MainActivity is defined in AndroidManifest.xml as android:launchMode="singleTop"
 * onNewIntent acts as an entrypoint whenever an intent is received pointing to MainActivity,
 * since we don't want to launch a new instance of the Activity.
 * (because we want to keep the stack of RouterTransactions)
 */
override fun onNewIntent(intent : Intent){
    setIntent(intent)
}
```